# Do I need to manually create relation tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

If I have two tables,

```
Person

PhoneNumbers
```

As it has a one-to-many relationship, do I have to manually create a third table like  `person_phone`, or will Hibernate automatically do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a one-to-many relation, you don't need a third table; `PhoneNumbers` would include a foreign key to the `Person` table.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you don't *need* a third table, you *can* have a third table (for optimization purposes, for instance). In this case, you can map the relationship as usual, plus adding the @JoinTable annotation:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html

Alternatively, you can find more information about it in the Hibernate documentation (see section 5.1.7.1. Using a foreign key or an association table):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e7541

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to manually create a third table like `person_phone`?

No, you don't have to.

Consider the relationship. It's one to many. i.e. a person may have many phone numbers. How would you map it without Hibernate? One table for Person and another table for PhoneNumbers with a foreign key to PersonsId. That's what Hibernate will do unless you instruct it otherwise, as mentioned by partenon.